# HP DV5 1211EM Hibernates

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I've installed a clean version of Windows 7 Pro on HP DV5 1211EM. The computer hibernates after 5-10 minutes. I've checked the temperature of the device and it's normal. The fans run perfectly too. Can anyone tell me where the issue is. It's very annoying.

One last note: the laptop screen was replaced as well and it's working fine. (during the installation & setup of windows the laptop did no hibernate.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've also  tried taking the battery out and running it off the cable and the problem still exists. The only time the computer does not hibernate is when it's in safe mode!

Comment: Did you check your Power Options settings in Control Panel? Maybe it is set to hibernate.

Comment: Yes that was one of the first things I checked.